# Reiterating is happening in my code and it keeps saying 50 than 50

Tags: python, random

```
import random
```

> The Wood And Food For Random

```
Good = ["Wood", "Food"]

Wood = 50
Food = 50
```

> The reiteration, how to fix?

```
while Wood != 0 or Food != 0:
    Stood = print(random.choice(Good))
    Bood = 0
```

> Something wrong with this part maybe?

```
    if Stood == "Wood":
        Wood += 1
        Food -= 1
        Bood += 1
    elif Stood == "Food":
        Food += 1
        Wood -= 1
        Bood += 1
    if Wood and Food == 50 and Bood == 1:
        exit()
    print(Wood)
    print(Food)
    if Wood == 0 or Food == 0:
        exit()
```

Comment: `if wood and food == 50` this is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: `if Wood and Food == 50` gets evaluated as `if Wood and (Food == 50)`, and since `Wood` is an `int`, as `if (Wood != 0)  and (Food == 50)`

Comment: `Stood = print(random.choice(Good))` after this `Stood` will be None since you assigning to it the result of `print` and not from `random.choice`